# eval refused to change string into object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval

I try to change a string into an object using eval but failed.

```
var obj ="{a:0, b:-1}";
eval(obj);
```

Error msg says "invalid label" but even this doesn't work

```
var obj="{'a':'0', 'b':'-1'}";
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when `eval`ing json, you have to put braces around it, so it should look like (otherwise it's not a complete javascript-statement):

```
eval('('+obj+')');
```

this solved the error, but the generated object isn't saved to any variable - so you might want to end up with something else, like:

```
eval('obj = '+obj);
```

this also makes a complete statement and, in addition, `obj` now is a "real" object.

Comment: That's interesting...Actually I didn't use brackets previously but instead put string into a literal array so it's something like: obj = eval("[string]"); and it worked. So I didn't notice that issue. Thanks. I'll try it now.

Comment: why do the `obj =` inside the `eval`? `eval` returns the result; simply assign that: `obj = eval('('+obj+')');` Do as little with `eval` as possible

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this too.

```
var obj=eval(" [{'a':'0', 'b':'-1'}] ");
alert(obj);
```